# How to Transform sklearn tfidf vector pandas output to a meaningful format

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have used sklearn to obtain tfidf scores for my corpus but the output is not in the format I wanted.

Code:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,3))
tfidf_matrix = vect.fit_transform(df_doc_wholetext['csv_text'])

df = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_matrix.toarray(),columns=vect.get_feature_names())

df['filename'] = df.index
```

**What I have:**

[image]

word1, word2, word3 could be any words in the corpus. I mentioned them as word1 , word2, word3 for example.

**What I need:**

[image]

I tried transforming it but it transforms all the columns to rows. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='word').stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['filename','word_name','score']
```

Output:

```
   filename word_name  score
0         0     word1   0.01
1         0     word2   0.04
2         0     word3   0.05
3         1     word1   0.02
4         1     word2   0.99
5         1     word3   0.07
```

**Update** for general column headers:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,1:].stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: I mentioned word1, word2, word3 for instance but they are actually words like 'personal' 'company' 'coverage'. Your code results in empty dataframe. I should have explained that in the question.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for this case. It takes all columns but the first one.

Comment: I am almost there but in my case the filename is the last instead of first. I tried df1 = df.iloc[:,-1].stack().reset_index() but it threw an error 'stack not found for series'

Comment: You're very close already: if the filename is the last use `df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].stack().reset_index()`. Without the `:` before the `-1` you select just the last column, i.e. a series that has no stack() method.